# Hover map area sprite with jquery

Tags: jquery, dictionary, css-sprites, area

I'm working on my first actual wordpress site and i'm having some troubles with some jquery. I really hope that someone can help me out here.

So what i want to do is to position my div background depending on the map area currently hovered.

I found an example here: http://ubytujnaslovensku.sk/sk/

What i got:
HTML:

```
<div id="front-cubus-wrapper">
        <div id="front-cubus"></div> 
        <div id="front-cubus-hover" style="background-position: 0px 0px;" ></div> 
        <img alt="cubus" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/cubus_index_blanko.png"  usemap="#map"/>
            <map id="map" name="map">
              <area title="Communication" alt="Communication" shape="poly" coords="119,101,286,34,347,55,180,124" href="#">
              <area title="Governance" alt="Governance" shape="poly" coords="59,79,228,17,281,34,115,99" href="#">
              <area title="Leadership" alt="Leadership" shape="poly" coords="55,78,223,16,173,2,3,58" href="#">
              <area title="Strategy" alt="Strategy" shape="poly" coords="179,127,2,61,6,133,179,207" href="#">
              <area title="Implementation" alt="Implementation" shape="poly" coords="179,212,6,138,9,206,180,286" href="#">
              <area title="Operation" alt="Operation" shape="poly" coords="180,290,9,210,12,278,179,362" href="#">
              <area title="Corporate" alt="Corporate" shape="poly" coords="182,126,225,110,223,341,183,359" href="#">
              <area title="Business units" alt="Business units" shape="poly" coords="230,108,271,91,265,319,228,340" href="#">
              <area title="Business functions" alt="Business functions" shape="poly" coords="275,89,313,73,305,294,268,317" href="#">
              <area title="Potential partner" alt="Potential partner" shape="poly" coords="315,71,351,55,342,272,308,292" href="#">
            </map>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#front-cubus-wrapper{
width:355px;
height:365px;
position:relative;
}

#front-cubus{
width:355px;
height:365px;
position: absolute;
background-image:url(images/insighttoimprove_website_cubus_index.png);
z-index:1;
}

#front-cubus-hover{
width:355px;
height:365px;
position: absolute;
background-image:url(images/insighttoimprove_website_cubus_index_hover.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
z-index:2;
}

#front-cubus-wrapper img{
position:absolute;
width:355px;
height:365px;
z-index:3;
}
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

var default_value = $("#front-cubus-hover").css("background-position");
if (default_value === "0px 0px") {
$('#map area').each(function() {

    $(this).hover(
        function() {
            var yposition = -1*365*($(this).index()+1); 
            $("#front-cubus-hover").css("background-position","0 "+yposition+"px"); 
},
        function() {
            $("#front-cubus-hover").css("background-position",default_value);
        }
    );
});
}
});
```

Comment: please make a JSFiddle ? did you make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on similar project. Here is my code with explanation.

HTML

```
<img src="images/car.jpg" alt="car" usemap="#carmap" width="1100px" height="700px" /> 
<map name="carmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,200,150" alt="door" href="#" class="door1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="453,404,533,704" alt="door" href="#" class="door2">
</map>

<div class="door1"></div>

<div class="door2"></div>
```

CSS

```
img{
    position: relative;
}

div.door1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    background: blue;
    pointer-events:none;  
}

div.door2{
    width: 180px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 453px;
    top: 404px;                
    background: url("images/tire-modified.jpg") no-repeat left top;
    pointer-events:none;  
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

jQuery

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("div.door1").hide();
        $("area.door1").mouseenter(function(){
            $("div.door1").show();
        });

        $("area.door1").mouseleave(function(){
            $("div.door1").hide();
        });

        $("area.door2").mouseenter(function(){
            $("div.door2").show();
        });

        $("area.door2").mouseleave(function(){
            $("div.door2").hide();
        });

    });
</script>
```

So, first I set the image with position relative and map with two areas on image. Now, on that map hover part I bind mouseenter and mouseleave events so that I can set my other divs(according to areas) I can set them with position absolute. Don't forget to add pointer-events:none; to your absolute elements so that none of the events applicable to those elements. Otherwise the blinking problem will be there. I hope it will be helpful to you.

Regular car-image.
[Regular car-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1pJI.jpg)

On-hover of the car tier(car tier image with absolute position).
[On-hover of the car tier(car tier image with absolute position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owTj8.jpg)